# Name generator (JS) and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a small website for me and some friends and want to put a name generator in it.
I am using :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
        <title>Donjons et Lardons</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="script/script.js"></script>
        <script src="script/generator.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- HEADER -->

    <header>
        <h1>Donjons et Lardons</h1>
    </header>
    <p class="big">Parce que tout est bon dans un donjon</p>


<!-- NAV -->


<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- The Collapsing items  -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"> </span> Héros</a></li>
        <li><a href="ludum.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>  Ludum Chronologia</a></li>
        <li><a href="lardon.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-piggy-bank"></span>  L'art du Lardon</a></li>
        <li><a href="coffre.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>  Le coffre à jouets</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- SECTION -->


 <!-- <p id="placeholder">

  </p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Rollin'</button>
  <script src="script/script.js"></script>
  <script src="css/style.css"></script>
-->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <section class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-1"></div> 
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">
      <button type="button" class="dice-roll btn btn-danger">roll dice</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">      
      <div id="dice-side-1" class="dice">0</div>
      <div id="dice-side-2" class="dice">0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-1"></div>  
  </section>

  <section class="row form-group">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2 id="status"></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </section>

   <section class="row form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-3"></div>  
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Besoin d'un nom ?</button>
      </div>
      <div id="h2" class="col-lg-5 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-3">
        <h2></h2>

      </div>
</div>


<!-- FOOTER -->
 <div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <footer>
        <p class="big">Surtout les moines ronchons</p>
    </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The JS code of the name generator is from here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/3gtDf/

I managed to put the button to ask a name, but nothing happen.

The html content is in the last section in the "container-fluid".
I linked to two JS files because I also have a dice generator and if I put both codes into the same file, the dice don't work.

Is the code working or Bootstrap making it bug?
Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: Have you tried to see if there is any error in the web console of your browser?
Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: Your pasted HTML code is incomplete. Please add the whole code snippet or how you added JavaScript code into the HTML page.

Comment: this codes works fine. Can u share all html ?

Comment: @Greg have you tried with the modifications I have written in my answer?

Comment: @Ludo

Yes it works fine, thanks.

I am still a little bit lost with Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Greg Great, so you can accept the answer by clicking on the check, so people know it has been answered ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code, it works with few modifications:

To call the generator function only when you click on your generator button:
add an `id` property to your generator button ex:`id="generator_btn"`

In generator.js replace

`$('button').click(function() {`
 by 
 `$('#generator_btn').click(function() {`

And put this in `$( document ).ready(function() {` ... `});`

`.ready` offers a way to run JavaScript code as soon as the page's Document Object Model (DOM) becomes safe to manipulate : https://api.jquery.com/ready/

You can also load the `generator.js` just before ending the `</body>` tag

Be careful:

- When you copy/paste the "random name generator" code from jsfiddle, as it does not copy the full code, as far as I am concerned, the var `nouns` was truncated.
- You load an old version of jquery, it does not seems to be a problem for the example, but if you use more recent functions of jquery it could be one.

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me and bootstrap is not making it bugged. There must be a problem on how you added the JavaScript in your page or something else that you did not share with us.